# Проблемы с jinga (django)

Tags: python, django, jinja2

Я пытаюсь создать веб сайт календаря который сможет отображать список задач. Вот `view.py`

```py
import calendar as calendar_engine # Используется calendar_engine что бы избежать колизий имен с моделькой


def render_calendar(request, path, year, month):
    try:
        calendar = Calendar.objects.get(path=path)
    except Calendar.DoesNotExist:
        return render(request, "Calendar/404.html", {"text": "calendar not found")
    c = calendar_engine.Calendar()
    tasks = {}
    for weak in c.monthdatescalendar(year, month):
        for date in weak: # date is datetime.date object
            task = Task()
            tasks[date] = task.get_day_tasks(date, calendar) # Функция возвращает список задач по конкретному дню. Её работоспособность гарантирована.
    context = {"month": c.monthdatescalendar(year, month), "tasks": tasks}
    return render(request, "Calendar/calendar.html", context)
```

`calendar.html`

```html
<table>
    {% for weak in month %}
        <tr>
            {% for date in weak %}
                <th> {{ tasks[date] }} </th>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>

    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Однако это не работает, так как jinja автоматом переводит `datetime.date` объект в строку  `(date(2021, 1, 1) -> 1 Jan 2021)` Так как в словаре нет такого ключа выходил `KeyError`. Можете помочь это исправить

---

Пробовал переводить все в строки:

```
 {'May 31, 2021': [], 'Jun 1, 2021': [<Task: Clementine Hopkins Placeat id id placeat eum harum sequi illo accusantium quidem aliquid tenetur dolorum ut et 1622540160>],
'Jun 2, 2021': [], 'Jun 3, 2021': [], 'Jun 4, 2021': [], 'Jun 5, 2021': [], 'Jun 6, 2021': [], 'Jun 7, 2021': [], 'Jun 8, 2021': [], 'Jun 9, 2021': [], 'Jun 10, 2021': [], 'Jun 11, 2021':
 [], 'Jun 12, 2021': [], 'Jun 13, 2021': [], 'Jun 14, 2021': [], 'Jun 15, 2021': [], 'Jun 16, 2021': [<Task: Quincy Tyson Alias dolorem perferendis elit quam 1623806280>], 'Jun 17, 2021': .... Много заданий
```

Но выходит другая ошибка:
`django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: '[date]' from 'tasks[date]'`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Значит у вас на самом деле вовсе не jinja

Comment: Сделайте ключи строками

Comment: Перевел ключе в текст, выходит ошибка. Jinja не может распознать почему то мой запрос. (В вопросе дополнение)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jinja не может адекватно работать со словарями, так что лучшее что я смог придумать:

```
                                {% for date_key, day_num in days.items %}
                                    {% if date == date_key %}
                                        {{ day_num }}
                                    {% endif %}
                                {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Jinja как раз **может** адекватно работать со словарями, но у вас не Jinja.